# Can't Change 100+ Size System Font

Tags: fonts, system, system-settings, resize

I accidentally changed the font size in system settings to over 100. Now when I log into my account, every text in menus is over 100, making everything ginormous. This makes going back to the system settings to change the font impossible since everything is so big, the buttons I need to click are several meters off screen.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Press `CTRL` `ALT` `F1`
2. Login with your normal credentials
3. Run `export DISPLAY=:0`
4. Run `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 'Ubuntu 10'`
5. Type `exit` and press enter
6. Press `ALT` `F7`
7. Login, and it should be fixed

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Getting stuck on the 3rd step:

(process:2486): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY

Comment: I think you need to log in first, and `export DISPLAY=:0` before running `gsettings`.

Comment: I have added `export DISPLAY=:0`

Comment: Show the font name with `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name` and use the name with a new size.