# How can I change desktop/system font size in Ubuntu using commands?

Tags: command-line, fonts

This is really silly but a computer from my classroom has got its font changed to a huge (ridiculous) one. The icons are insanely big and there's no way to navigate through any program, not even system preferences. The only window that is still normaly-sized is the konsole. So I'm wondering: is there a command to edit system font size or a command to change back these settings?

I tried to search this online but I'm not getting any results. I saw some things about "gnome" but nothing worked. I also tried to follow this link ([Can't Change 100+ Size System Font](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628992/cant-change-100-size-system-font)) but the 'DISPLAY' part doesn't work and showed an error message. I won't be able to access the computer until Monday, so I just wanted some info and see if there's something I could do about it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What to do apparently depends on which kind of setting causes the big fonts. Running this command might help:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/desktop/interface/
```

Comment: Noted, thank you very much!